# Enabling HTTPOnly in Secure in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

We have enabled HttpOnly for our site.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This is working fine, when we accessing the site in non-secure region. But in Secure live region(Https), this is not working and we able to get the session keys. how to mitigate it. any idea whould be much helpful.

Im trying in Asp.Net 2.0

Comment: What exactly is "not working"? Do you see an error somewhere? Do you not see the cookies on the server side?

Comment: @tom I am able to access the Sessionid cookies via javascript, and httponly is not set while checking through the chrome browser-resources section.

Comment: did you ensure you have cleared all the old cookies before trying?

Comment: @Ramesh Yes all cleared, tried in many PCs

Answer (score 2):

I have bunch of solutions here dude.. Just feel free to choose among these solutions which caters your needs

- In Global.asax, overwrite the Session_Start method as follows.

  ```
  <script runat="server">       
   void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {

      if(Response.Cookies.Count > 0)
      foreach(string s in Response.Cookies.AllKeys)
       if(s == System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName ||
              s.ToLower().Equals("asp.net_sessionid") )
      Response.Cookies[s].HttpOnly = false;
  ```

  }

**reference:http://nerd.steveferson.com/2007/09/14/act-sessionid-and-login-problems-with-asp-net-20/#.URiXUqWzd9c**

- Note that in ASP.NET 1.1 the System.Net.Cookie class does not support
  the HttpOnly property. Therefore, to add an HttpOnly attribute to the
  cookie you could add the following code to your application's

  Application_EndRequest event handler in Global.asax:

  ```
  protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    string authCookie = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;

    foreach (string sCookie in Response.Cookies)
    {
          if (sCookie.Equals(authCookie))
          {
                Response.Cookies[sCookie].Path += ";HttpOnly";
          }
    }
  }
  ```

**reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dansellers/archive/2006/03/13/550947.aspx**

- Add this to your Global.asax

  ```
  void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (Response.Cookies.Count > 0)
     {
         foreach (string s in Response.Cookies.AllKeys)
         {
             if (s == "ASP.NET_SessionId")
             {
                 Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].HttpOnly = false;
             }
         }
     }
  ```

  }

**reference: from this forum http://forums.asp.net/p/955272/1177574.aspx#1177574**
You could also try this Post [HttpOnly Cookies on ASP.NET 1.1](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HttpOnlyCookiesOnASPNET11.aspx) by Scott Hanselman but its ASP.NET 1.1

Comment: nope, we have tried all four options above, none of them are helped.

Comment: @bot: I'm confused by your answer--why are you setting `HttpOnly` to `false`?