# Why HttpOnly in Secured Asp.Net doesn't appear in Response Header?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-headers, owasp

**Note :** Please read first before down voting or pointing to another reference.

I am trying to set HttpOnly in Web.config but HttpOnly doesn't appear in response header.

```
<system.web>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" lockItem="true"/>
    <authentication mode="None" />
</system.web>
```

but upon checking in chrome the HttpOnly is missing?

```
Set-Cookie:user_key_sample=1480924786; domain=somedomainhere; path=/; secure
```

I was expecting it to be :

```
Set-Cookie:user_key_sample=1480924786; domain=somedomainhere; path=/; secure; HttpOnly;
```

I did a research and found these links:

- [Enabling HttpOnly in Secure in Asp.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807233/enabling-httponly-in-secure-in-asp-net) but haven't resolve.
- [HttpOnly Cookies on ASP.NET 1.1](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HttpOnlyCookiesOnASPNET11.aspx) - ( Can it be done in Web.config? )
- Also read some article the if you have secured cookies it automatically overwrite your Web.config setting and remove HttpOnly. (can't remember the link)

**Question :**
Is there a way to achieve goal using Web.config only?
Is it worth to have HttpOnly and secure at the same time? Actually OWASP Scanning is looking for HttpOnly flag in my response.

Comment: How is your cookie actually created?

Comment: Since we're using Federated Authentication (SSO) I assume it was created upon login

Comment: I mean, do you create the cookie explicitly in code? Is it created by an Owin middleware? By an IIS module?

Comment: No, I'am not creating the cookie but by IIS module

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. Show the code or refer to a specific module.

Comment: Sorry men my bad, we're creating the cookie using IHttpModule, I guest that the reason why even I have setting in web config it was overwrite by code.